# xslt for-each-group question

Tags: xslt

I have a xml need to group by category
I try to use

```
<xsl:for-each-group  select="ItemList/Item"  group-by="CategoryID">
```

How can I get the CategoryName, CategoryID or any information related to Category
during the transformation?

Original XML

```
<ItemList>
<Item>
    <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Book</CategoryName>
    <ItemName>ASP.NET</ItemName>
    <ItemDetails>ASP.NET12345</ItemDetails>
</Item>
<Item>
    <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Book</CategoryName>
    <ItemName>PHP</ItemName>
    <ItemDetails>PHP12345</ItemDetails>
</Item>
<Item>
    <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Tool</CategoryName>
    <ItemName>ToolAbcde</ItemName>
    <ItemDetails>sth details</ItemDetails>
</Item></ItemList>
```

New XML

```
<NewXML>
<Category>
    <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Book</CategoryName>
    <ItemList>
        <Item>
            <ItemName>ASP.NET</ItemName>
            <ItemDetails>ASP.NET12345</ItemDetails>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemName>PHP</ItemName>
            <ItemDetails>PHP12345</ItemDetails>
        </Item>
        <ItemName>PHP</ItemName>
    </ItemList>
</Category>
<Category>
    <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Tool</CategoryName>
    <ItemList>
        <Item>
            <ItemName>ToolAbcde</ItemName>
            <ItemDetails>sth details</ItemDetails>
        </Item>
    </ItemList>
</Category></NewXML>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The xslt spec has an extensive doucmentation on grouping, complete with examples at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group. You are probably looking for the `current-group()` and `current-grouping-key()` functions. Also

> Within the sequence constructor, **the context item is the initial item of the relevant group**, the context position is the position of this item among the sequence of initial items (one item for each group) arranged in processing order of the groups, the context size is the number of groups, the current group is the group being processed, and the current grouping key is the grouping key for that group.

Meaning that these two expressions would be equivalent inside xsl:for-each-group: `CategoryId` and `current-group()[1]/CategoryId`. Since CategoryId is the grouping key this is also the same as `current-grouping-key()`. Here is a complete example for your use case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <NewXml>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="ItemList/Item" group-by="CategoryID">
                <Category>
                    <CategoryID><xsl:value-of select="CategoryID" /></CategoryID>
                    <CategoryName><xsl:value-of select="CategoryName" /></CategoryName>
                    <ItemList>
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <Item>
                                <ItemName><xsl:value-of select="ItemName" /></ItemName>
                                <ItemDetails><xsl:value-of select="ItemDetails" /></ItemDetails>
                            </Item>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ItemList>
                </Category>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </NewXml>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is this for-each-group element rather new? C# XslCompiledTransform doesn't allow me to compile

Comment: @Trio Cheung. It's not new but it's xslt2.0 which shamefully is not supported natively by C#